# Are physical devices necessary for android, ios and blackberry testing

Tags: android, ios, blackberry, device

Buying devices to test your apk/ipa/alx on different android/ios/blackberry phones is getting heavy burden on pocket since it turns to be a dead investment very fast as technology is progressing too fast and you can't just keep on buying to know your app's user experience.

Is there any company that provides the services to save our dead investment? I've explored Keynote DeviceAnywhere which is pretty good but the rates are quite high.

I'm waiting for a solution asap.

Thanks.

Comment: http://www.perfectomobile.com/ provide the service same like device anywhere you can compare both rates so it might be help or less your burden

Answer (score 5):

Definitely.

I am not familiar with Eclipse or the Android simulators/emulators (nor BB or winPhone 7), but in any case you **want** to test on the real thing.

Even if the behavior is the same (some times it isn't), the performance is completely different between a real device and a simulator.

Comment: If you develop for android and you are an independent developer or very small company, I think it's OK to buy only the devices you can afford. But there are so many different adroid devices out there that perhaps you should put a disclaimer on your app's page, along the lines of "Tested on XX, YY running android XX.X"

Answer (score 1):

**Android** 
Definitely YES. Applications run munch faster on devices than on emulator. In the long run , buying devices will save developers time thus save you money. The best devices for developers are Nexus line unaffected by OEM software  (think of Samsung Touchwiz , HTC Sense).
[Samsung](http://developer.samsung.com/home.do) lets you use their real device over the network for a certain period of time.

**iOS**
YES . The simulator is pretty close to reality. If you're on budget, you may buy second hand :

- iphone 4 or wait for the upcoming iphone 5
- iPad only if you're
  targeting this support.

Add the developer licence extra cost too , to run on a device you must have a licence . iOS developer Standard = 99 USD and more for Enterprise Program = 299 usd

**Blackberry**
Don't know

Comment: BlackBerry simulators are more realistic is several ways (vs. iOS or Android), but there are still bugs that manifest differently in sims vs. real devices (or vice versa).  The performance, running on your desktop computer is also not realistic (e.g. slow, just like Android).  And, some features which are tightly tied to hardware still require real devices to adequately test.  I don't think you need every single model of BlackBerry for testing, but the answer is still pretty much the same as for Android and iOS.

Comment: Perhaps the android version is slow because it is an actual **emulator** (emulates target hardware CPU in software). In iOS it's the opposite: The iOS **simulator** (runs equivalent API in native, x86 code) is almost always faster than the device (unless you use some edge-case, rare OpenGL feature that is implemented more efficiently on the device than in desktop)

Comment: Blakcberry simulator most of proper realistic i think there are not need to purchase blakcberry device we have also publish more then app without testing device working fine.